# How to get scroll current position upon CollectionChange event in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, screen, visible, items

I've a Xamarin chat app, when i receive new messages it scrolls to the recent received message.
I want that to happen if i'm seeing the must recent messages, otherwise if User scrolls to older messages and a new message arrives, i want to be shown a button (like in team) saying "new" and if you click you scroll to the recent message.

The Problem here is that in order to do that i must be able to now what messages user is seeing in the screen, at least know the bottom screen message or just get scroll current position! After knowing that i can do the rest by myself.

This is my OnAppearing method:

```
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        if (viewModel.Messages.Count == 0)
        {
            viewModel.LoadItemsCommand.Execute(null);
        }

        viewModel.Messages.CollectionChanged += (sender, e) =>
        {
            //GET SCROLL CURRENT POSITION HERE!
            var target = viewModel.Messages[viewModel.Messages.Count - 1];

            ItemsListView.ScrollTo(target, ScrollToPosition.End, false);
        };            
    }
```

Thank you all!

Comment: You need to show us the relevant code.  We don't have any idea how your UI is built, so it's difficult to make any suggestions on how to implement the feature you want.

Comment: Sure Jason, thanks for the tip!

Comment: I've tried but i'm not able to use this "ScrollViewer" don't know where to get it

Comment: sorry, that was a WPF post.

Comment: How can i get scroll bar current position inside CollectionChange Event?

Comment: Hey refer this https://www.xamboy.com/2018/08/30/exploring-a-chat-ui-in-xamarin-forms-part-3/

Comment: THanks Anand it looks reaaly a good exaple of what i want, after i leave my work i will try it and let you know if it worked. If  it worked then you can formulate a answer about this article so i can vote up and accept it if you want.

Comment: @Anand I was looking at the code you suggested, it it looks like a solution... but it as a lot more then what i need.. I already have everything set to work i just don't know how to get Scroll current position  when CollectionChanged event triggers?? If i don't figure out this then i will redo my approach and implement the one you suggested

Comment: @MarchalPT ok marchal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i find the way of getting the scroll current position!!

Basically if you have a ListView like me once it already contains a scroll by default you can just do like this:

```
        YourListViewName.Scrolled += (sender, e) =>
        {
            var scrollCurrentVerticalPosition = e.ScrollY;                
        };
```

For my case instead of making the call inside CollectionChanged event I had to do this:

Create a private variable:

```
private bool scrollPositionEnd = true;
```

And inside OnAppearing method:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    if (viewModel.Messages.Count == 0)
    {
        viewModel.LoadItemsCommand.Execute(null);
    }

    viewModel.Messages.CollectionChanged += (sender, e) =>
    {            
        if (scrollPositionEnd == true)
        {
            ScrollToEnd();
        }
        else if (GetLastMessage().UserId != UserId) //so it wont trigger on your own messages
        {
            NewMessagesButton.IsVisible = true;
        }
    };    

    ItemsListView.Scrolled += (sender, e) =>
    {
        if (e.ScrollY == 0) //when scroll is in bottom ScrollY value is 0 
        {
            scrollPositionEnd = true;

            //if you manually scroll down until the new message
            NewMessagesButton.IsVisible = false;
        }
        else
        {
             scrollPositionEnd = false;
        }
    };
 }
```

Auxiliary methods:

```
    //If you click the button event
    private void ButtonScrollClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ScrollToEnd();
    }

    private void ScrollToEnd()
    {
        NewMessagesButtonFrame.IsVisible = false;
        Message target = GetLastMessage();
        ItemsListView.ScrollTo(target, ScrollToPosition.End, false);
    }

    private Message GetLastMessage()
    {
        return viewModel.Messages[viewModel.Messages.Count - 1];
    }
```

Thank you guys for you tips and if you enjoy my answer fill free to vote it up :)